# new cardano wallet takes time to sync, not able to get balance of wallet

Tags: wallet

i am using docker compose for running cardano server,
and using cardano-wallet-js package for interacting.

my issue is whenever i create new wallet, the wallet sync form 0 and it takes too much time

to create wallet

```
const genwallet = async () => {
  try {
    let parameters = await cardano.Seed.generateRecoveryPhrase()
    let words = cardano.Seed.toMnemonicList(parameters);

    let passphrase = 'tangoCrypto';
    let name = 'wallet';

    let wallet = await walletServer.createOrRestoreShelleyWallet(name, words, passphrase);
    console.log(wallet);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
genwallet()
```

get wallet info

```
  id: '344e120866c28fd706b2eff539da61b02282a3df',
  address_pool_gap: 20,
  balance: {
    total: { quantity: 0, unit: 'lovelace' },
    available: { quantity: 0, unit: 'lovelace' },
    reward: { quantity: 0, unit: 'lovelace' }
  },
  assets: { total: [], available: [] },
  delegation: { next: [], active: { status: 'not_delegating' } },
  name: 'wallet',
  passphrase: { last_updated_at: '2022-04-26T11:21:24.396104055Z' },
  state: { status: 'syncing', progress: { quantity: 0, unit: 'percent' } },
  tip: {
    height: { quantity: 0, unit: 'block' },
    epoch_number: 0,
    time: '2017-09-23T21:44:51Z',
    absolute_slot_number: 0,
    slot_number: 0
  },
```

in this state syncing progress start from 0 for every new wallet, i can't use this wallet till it sync.

Comment: What do the logs of cardano-node say? I personally find it easier hosting the node as-is (i.e. outside of a container) and [there is a simple guide](https://learn.lovelace.academy/getting-started/running-a-full-node/) on how to do it.

Comment: no logs only 200 ok

Comment: it is creating full node wallet. A full-node wallet basically means that it has to synchronize and download the complete blockchain for every new wallets you create then only you can able to send transactions and interact with the wallet.

ref - https://developers.cardano.org/docs/integrate-cardano/creating-wallet-faucet/#cardano-wallets